# How to only allow access to bot for subset of employees from a given organization?

Tags: botframework

I want to provide a bot that can only be accesible for certain users within a company. How should I go about that?

## Different Channels

### Skype for business

I guess this narrows down the problem to only identify the subset of the users as all the users in Skype for business would be from the organization.

### MS Teams

Is this similar to the previous case? I understand that anyone with the bot id could chat with the bot.

### Other non company restricted channels

I guess with this one the bot will always be exposed to external accounts and I'll need to authenticate before answering any message.

## Authentication

How would this work? Would I store a token for each user for each channel were they login? With that check the ADD for attributes in order to decide what to provide to that user?

Comment: Do you want implement your own authentication strategy to restrict user to access your bot?

Comment: Actually I’m trying to understand what I need to do to restrict access. I don’t want to implement my own authentication strategy if it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to restrict access to a bot - it will be visible to all users. You will need to build authentication into your bot to limit who can communicate with it. There is documentation you can read for [Adding authentication to your bot via Azure Bot Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) or to [Authenticate requests via Direct Line API 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) (also available via Direct Line API 1.1) by use of tokens. You would use this to authenticate AAD credentials.

Comment: You mean within a given organization, right?
Becuase I tried accessing a bot in one organization's Skype for Business from another organization's Skype for Business account and wasn't able too. 
AlthoughI was able to access the MS Teams bot from another MS Teams account using the MS Teams App Id of the bot

Comment: Assuming it's an available feature, accessing a bot across an org would be up to the tenant admin for that SfB or MS Teams account. Federated domains could also make this at least possible which may explain why you can access a bot across accounts.